# Push notification via C# socket

Tags: c#, react-native, socket.io

I want to send push notifications via C# socket server to React Native. On react native side, I use socket.io. React Native connects to the server, but never receives a message back.

React Native code:

```
socket = io.connect('xx.xx.xx.xx:2201');

    socket.on((messages) => {
      console.log("response" + JSON.stringify(messages));   
});
```

Server Code:

```
 public static void StartListening()
    {
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];  
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

        /
        Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(10);
            while (true)
            {
                Socket handler = listener.Accept();
                data = null;
            int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
            data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
            Console.WriteLine("Receieved message and sent: " + data);
            byte[] msg1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("jjjjjj");
            handler.Send(msg1);
                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handler.Close();
            }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is help you.

```
import SocketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
this.socket = SocketIOClient('xx.xx.xx.xx:2201', {
        transports: ['websocket']
    });
 this.socket.on('message', (message) => { // you can send 'message' emit from server side and than get the on by using 'message' keyword
     console.log(message)
 });
```

Comment: I can't emit from server because the server is written in c#.